# SUM a GROUP BY with a HAVING cause and CASE- Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I've managed to find a very manual work around but I'm sure there is a much simpler method to what I'm hoping to achieve. Essentially I'm trying to get find out how many redempetions there are for customers who have achieved 'points' (sales vs their multiplier) and reached a threshold (2000) as one number
Example table:

```
ID      SALES    Multiplier    
10R46   1140.0   Two
10R46   1123.5   Two
100R91  1115.3   One
10R91   2.0      One
10M95   800.0    One
10M95   600.0    Two
10M95   33.0     Zero
```

The current code I'm using is:

```
SELECT ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Multiplier = 'Two' THEN (trunc(sales * 2)) 
        WHEN Multiplier = 'One' THEN (trunc(sales * 1))
        ELSE 0 END) as points
FROM transactions
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Multiplier = 'Two' THEN (trunc(sales * 2)) 
        WHEN Multiplier = 'One' THEN (trunc(sales * 1))
        ELSE 0 END) > 2000
```

From which I'm putting the result into a temporary table and running a trunc sum on top

```
SELECT SUM(trunc(points/2000))
FROM temp_table
```

Which gives the ideal result  (3 in this case) of how many redemptions there are.

So my question for the great minds, how do I simplify this and have one query without a temp table?

Comment: Can't you put `HAVING points > 2000` in the first query? Otherwise, doesn't `SELECT INTO` work in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Since I'm trying to find customers who are eligible the group by needs to summarise the points by customer (ID)  - and yes INTO does work - trying to avoid the creation of a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with a sub-query.

```
select sum(trunc(points/2000))
from (
SELECT ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Multiplier = 'Two' THEN (trunc(sales * 2)) 
        WHEN Multiplier = 'One' THEN (trunc(sales * 1))
        ELSE 0 END) as points
FROM transactions
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Multiplier = 'Two' THEN (trunc(sales * 2)) 
        WHEN Multiplier = 'One' THEN (trunc(sales * 1))
        ELSE 0 END) > 2000
) t
```

Another option with `sum` window function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN Multiplier = 'Two' THEN (trunc(sales * 2)) 
                     WHEN Multiplier = 'One' THEN (trunc(sales * 1))
                ELSE 0 END
               )/2000
           ) OVER()
FROM transactions
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Multiplier = 'Two' THEN (trunc(sales * 2)) 
        WHEN Multiplier = 'One' THEN (trunc(sales * 1))
        ELSE 0 END) > 2000
```

Comment: Thanks a million - for those reading through - the Sub-Query was the winner on this one, didn't attempt the 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simpler query:

```
SELECT SUM(trunc(points/2000))
FROM (SELECT t.ID, SUM(TRUNC(sales * mult)) as points
      FROM transactions t JOIN
           (VALUES ('One', 1), ('Two', 2)) v(Multiplier, mult)
           ON t.Multiplier = v.Multiplier
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING points > 2000
     ) t;
```

I even think you can eliminate the subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(TRUNC(sales * mult) / 2000) OVER ()
FROM transactions t JOIN
     (VALUES ('One', 1), ('Two', 2)) v(Multiplier, mult)
     ON t.Multiplier = v.Multiplier
GROUP BY ID
HAVING points > 2000
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```